# Trying to store a series of arrays inside a Redux-toolkit slice but only getting one

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get some data back from my database and map over it to display in the client (using react/redux-toolkit).

The current structure of the data is a series of arrays filled with objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    prize_id: 1,
    book_id: 2,
    author_id: 2,
  }
]
[
  {
    id: 1,
    prize_id: 1,
    book_id: 1,
    author_id: 1,
  }
]
```

The front end is only displaying one of the arrays at a time despite needing to display both. I think the problem is in how my redux is set up. Becuase when I `console.log` the `action.payload` I get back just one of the arrays, usually the second one.

Here is how my redux slices and actions look:

slice:

```
const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'books',
  initialState: {
    booksByYear: [], //possibly the source of the problem
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(actions.fetchBooksByYear.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload)
      state.booksByYear = action.payload
    })
  },
})
```

action:

```
export const fetchBooksByYear = createAsyncThunk(
  'books/get books by prize and year year',
  async ({ prizeId, prizeYear }) => {
    const data = await api.getBooksByPrizeAndYear(prizeId, prizeYear.year)
    return data
  }
```

Here is how I am fetching the data from my component:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetch.fetchPrizeYears(prizeId))
  }, [dispatch])

  const booksByYear = prizeYears.map((year, id) => {
    console.log(year)
    return <PrizeLists key={id} prizeYear={year} prizeId={prizeId} />
  })
```

```
export default function PrizeLists(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const listOfBooks = useSelector((state) => state.books.booksByYear)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetch.fetchBooksByYear(props))
  }, [dispatch])
```

Previously it was working when the call
[was being made without redux](https://github.com/rupert-denton/biblion/blob/main/src/components/widgets/PrizeLists.jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `booksByYear` is expected to be an array of arrays, is that correct? For example:

```js
booksByYear: [
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      prize_id: 1,
      book_id: 2,
      author_id: 2,
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      prize_id: 1,
      book_id: 1,
      author_id: 1,
    }
  ]
]
```

The slice setup seems fine, I think the problem might be `api.getBooksByPrizeAndYear`.
Because the `action.payload` in the callback of `builder.addCase` is returned by the corresponding `createAsyncThunk`, which is `fetchBooksByYear` in your case.
So if `action.payload` is not something you're expecting, there's a high chance that the API is not responding the correct dataset in the first place.

I'm not sure about the use case in you app, if the API will only return one array at a time, you probably want to merge `action.payload` with `state.booksByYear` instead of replacing it.

---

Oh, now I know why you said `initialState.booksByYear` might be the problem! Yes, it is a problem because from you code it seems that you want to "group" those books by `{ prizeYear, prizeId }`, and display the books in each group on UI. Due to the fact that there's only one array at the moment, the last fulfilled action will always overwrite the previous fulfilled action because of how we handle API response (`state.booksByYear = action.payload`).

In this case I think it makes more sense to leave those books in the component by using `useState`. But if you really want to store those books in redux, you could try making `initialState.booksByYear` into a Map-like object, and find the corresponding array by `{ prizeYear, prizeId }` from `<PrizeLists />`.

For example:

```js
// Slice
// You may want to implement the hash function that suits your case!
// This example may lead to a lot of collisions!
export const hashGroupKey = ({ prizeYear, prizeId }) => `${prizeYear}_${prizeId}`

const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'books',
  initialState: {
    // We can't use Map here because it's non serializable.
    // key: hashGroupKey(...), value: Book[]
    booksMap: {}
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(actions.fetchBooksByYear.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const key = hashGroupKey(action.meta.arg)
      state.booksMap[key] = action.payload
    })
  },
})

// PrizeLists
import { hashGroupKey } from '../somewhere/book.slice';

const listOfBooks = useSelector((state) => {
  const key = hashGroupKey(props)
  return state.books.booksMap[key] ?? []
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I have updated the OP with some more code and a snippet from previous iteration that worked. The api is fired for every year in an array of years (eg. 2020, 2021) etc.

Comment: Thanks @deadant88! I've edited my answer based on your code, let me know if you have any question!

Comment: Brilliant, I can just keep them in the component using, ``useState`` which makes it easy - I am still unsure when best to use Redux vs ``useState`` - I sort of got the impression that it is best to just use Redux for everything!

Comment: Most of the time redux store is used to store global, app-wide states, but It's also a good place to cache data for later use (basically what RTK Query is doing). A common example is YouTube; if you search for a video, click it in the result list then click go back, you'll see that the search result gets loaded instantly because you're actually seeing cached data instead of refetching them from the server.

Comment: Also, most of the states in components will not be used anymore after the component (pages) is unmounted; but once they're stored in the store, they will not be cleared until we explicitly do so by dispatching actions, which means a lot of memories could be wasted on storing stuff we don't need if we're not being careful. I think leaving those states in the components by using `useState` could be way more convenient, and way more easier to maintain in the long run.